Charging a BMS and providing power at different voltages
I've designed a BMS based on the HX-2S-JH20. The BMS design itself is clear to me, but as I want to use a 12 V DC plug for charging. The BMS takes 8.3..9 V, the circuit takes 5 V. I wasn't quite sure on how to hook this up.
I'm using 2 linear voltage regulators, both with a max input of 30 V. One outputs 9 V for the BMS to charge the cells, and the other takes the 9 V from voltage regulator 1 or the BMS and converts it to 5 V for the circuit to use (I hope :) )
Do you guys have any input on this? The part of the schematic I'm unsure about is boxed in red.
The 9 V is of course hooked up to ground, something I forgot to draw in the schematic.


Where's your actual charging circuit?

Damn, you are right, I kinda thought the BMS would handle that, but it doesn't include charging ‍♂️. Let me update the schematic, because I had another version where I wanted to use a TP5100.

You also need to provide proper power path management for powering your load while charging to prevent overcharging. Have a good search, there are literally hundreds of questions on here asking the same thing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't use multiple names for the same net, because just confuses the reader and will also confuse yourself when routing, which is why you "forgot" to connect 9V- to GND. This schematic shorts nets for P+, to B+, to 9V+...makes intent very unclear. And where battery actually would be connected is unclear too since nothing is labeled as battery connector.

@SanderSlagman - Hi, I see you made a substantial change to the question, after receiving an answer to your original question. That isn't allowed, as it becomes a "chameleon question" i.e. it keeps changing. Answers to question rev X look obsolete/incomplete when it gets changed to rev X+1. This can upset those who write answers & can result in your question being ignored / downvoted / flagged for mod attention (and likely closure). Edits can only be used to clarify or improve a question, not change it. || In this situation, where your original question was answered {...}

{...} the correct etiquette is to consider how that question was answered. Then ask a new question, include a link to this original question in your new question & a short narrative explaining what has changed (to avoid people thinking it's a duplicate of the original one). Make sure the new question is complete & "standalone", even though it should contain a link back to this one. || I have reversed the edit here. You can find the added text & image links in the revision history, for you to use in your new question. TY

@SamGibson I'm sorry, for me it felt like a natural continuance that sort of answered this question, but you are absolutely right, as I immediately asked a new one, I've moved the information to a new question. Is it okay to link it in this question?

A very warm welcome to the site. Your question and schematic refer to an 'LDO voltage regulator' but the 7805 linear voltage regulator you're using isn't an LDO part, far from it. It has a Vin(min) of 7V for its 5V output. Have corrected this throughout your question but you'll have to edit your schematic to fix that. Also corrected on your other question associated with this one. Thanks.

A Li-ion battery requires two devices:

A BMS
A Charger

A BMS is not a charger. A charger is not a BMS. A linear voltage regulator is not a charger, nor a BMS.
Both devices are required.
You have one: a BMS. You need the other: a charger.
A Li-ion charger does two things:

It limits the charging current during bulk charging
It limits the battery voltage at the end of charge

A BMS cannot limit the voltage or the current. A BMS is just an On/Off switch.
A standard voltage regulator doesn't limit the current. It does set the voltage, but yours doesn't set it to the correct voltage.

Thanks for the input!
